# Matlab: make dummys out of variables but keep the variable name in a Dataset

Tags: matlab, statistics, dataset, dummy-variable

I have a dataset variable called ds in Matlab which I am using for Regression.

Most of the variables in ds are categorical, they have a certain amount of fixed values they can take. I would like to turn all those variables in ds into dummys, but keep the names.

I will give an example:

The variable speed can take following values: 0, 10, 20, 30, 40. So from this I want to create 5 dummy variables. I know how to do this. But I would like for the dataset to set the dummy variable names to speed_0, speed_10, speed_20...
Is there any function or something that can do this for me, because my dataset contains lots of categorical variables and I can't input the names for all of them manually.

Regards,

Sven

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for but take a look at genvarname:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/genvarname.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get you right. Are you trying to obtain something like this?:

```
DummyVarNames = strcat('speed_',strtrim(cellstr(num2str([10:10:100]'))));
```

Comment: Hi Ivea, yes but I would like to have this done automatically, if possible, cause its also not very practical for me to create thos num2str vectors for 100 different variables.

Comment: @Ggwp1399 : I am not sure to get you right, but you should have your values in hand (e.g. you want to create 200 different dummy variable names corresponding to numbers 1 to 400 with step size 2. So: `DummyVarNames = strcat('speed_',strtrim(cellstr(num2str([1:2:400]'))));`

So, I don't know what exactly you mean by word _practical_ ..?

Comment: Nono, I have 100 Variables, all of which are 'categorical'. Each of them are supposed to be split up. So Variable 1 has 6 distinct categories, Variable 2 has 10 categories etc.